# Efficient query for finding duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to query a table for duplicate deposit records, where two deposits made at one cash terminal, for the same amount, within a certain time window, are considered duplicate records.  I've started  working on a query now, but I would appreciate any advice or suggestions on doing this 'properly'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you'd do a self join to the same table, and put your "duplicate" criteria in the join conditions.

E.g.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Transactions t1
        inner join
    Transactions t2
        on
            t1.Terminal = t2.Terminal and
            t1.Amount = t2.Amount and
            DATEDIFF(minute,t2.TransactionDate,t1.TransactionDate) between 0 and 10 and
            t1.TransactionID > t2.TransactionID /* prevent matching the same row */
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple aggregate

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   col1, col2, col3, ...
HAVING
   COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Don't include your identity/key/PK column: this will be unique per row and mess up the aggregate.

To get a row to remove or keep, do a MAX or MIN on that

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, col3, ...,
   MAX(IDCol) AS RowToDelete,
   MIN(IDCol) AS RowToKeep
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   col1, col2, col3, ...
HAVING
   COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Of course, with 3 duplicates then do a "keep".

Edit:

For rows within a time window, use a self join or window/ranking function

Comment: Yours is better for finding exact duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, but to group on the difference between deposit times of two records will prove difficult.  @Damien_The_Unbeliever has a more flexible query.